# Expected value of the investment

Tags: statistics

Suppose a sum of $1000$ pounds is invested with annual interest $5\%$
for $X$ years, where $X \sim \operatorname{Geom}(1/4)$. 
Compute the expected value of the investment’s worth at the end of the $X$ years.

I found the expected value of $X$ to be $4$, but I'm not sure what to do next?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189)
Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others
there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people
will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include some motivation,
and an explanation of your own attempts.

Comment: So, you think that 1000 pounds sitting in a bank with 5% interest for an undetermined number of years will on average be worth only 4 pounds when withdrawn? EDIT: Oh, I see what you did: you determined the average number of years it will be in the account as 4.

Comment: @Geoffrey $X$ is the duration in years, not in pounds.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes, I just realized that. I guess I didn't read his statement carefully enough.

Comment: It´s your turn to try to understand the given answer  (by secretlyaneconomist). Give a reply if you have any questions or not.

Comment: @callculus lol, could you be any more condescending? I understand the question and the answer perfectly fine without having to read what the answerer posted. My only mistake was assuming that the OP would know enough to know that he didn't need to calculate E(X).

Comment: @Geoffrey Sorry my comment was not addressed to you but rather to the OP Cathrine. But a comment for an OP cannot be addressed by using @.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value after $x$ years is $1000\times(1.05^x)$. The Expected value, by definition, is $\sum_{x=1}^\infty 1000\times(1.05^x)\times P(X=x)$ For the geometric distribution with probability $p$ we have $P(X=x)=(1-p)^{x-1}p$. So the expected value is $\sum_{x=1}^\infty 1000\times(1.05^x)\times (1-p)^{x-1}p$ which can be written $1000\times1.05p\sum_{x=1}^\infty (1.05(1-p))^{x-1} $ Using the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series (for this to be valid we need $|1.05(1-p)|<1$ we get:
$1000\times1.05p\times \frac{1}{1-1.05(1-p)}$ So plug in $p=1/4$ and you should get the answer.